# Summable ideals can be written as $\{A: \sup_k \mu_k(A \setminus \{1,\ldots,n\})\to 0\}$

Tags: set-theory, ideals

Fix a function $f: \mathbf{N} \to [0,\infty)$ such that $\sum_{n\ge 1}f(n)=\infty$. Then, we define the *summable ideal*
$$
\textstyle \mathcal{I}_f:=\{A\subseteq \mathbf{N}: \sum_{n \in A}f(n)<\infty\}.
$$

Moreover, given a (finitely additive) measure $\mu: \mathcal{P}(\mathbf{N}) \to [0,\infty]$ such that $\mu(\{n\})<\infty$ for all $n$, we denote its support by $\mathrm{supp}(\mu):=\{n \in \mathbf{N}: \mu(\{n\})\neq 0\}$.

> **Question.** Prove that there exist a partition $\{I_1,I_2,\ldots\}$ of $\mathbf{N}$ and a sequence of measures $(\mu_k)$ such that $\mathrm{supp}(\mu_k)=I_k$ for all $k$ and
>   $$
> \mathcal{I}_f=\{A\subseteq \mathbf{N}: \lim_{n\to \infty} \sup_{k\ge 1}\mu_k(I_k \cap A \setminus \{1,\ldots,n\})=0\}.
> $$

This fact appears as a comment [at p.42](https://books.google.com/books?id=IP7TCQAAQBAJ&pg=PA42) in Farah's book "Analytic Quotients: Theory of Liftings for Quotients over Analytic Ideals on the Integers"; hence, it is probably an easy question.

Edit: As easy observations, we can write every summable ideal $\mathcal{I}_f$ as
$$
\textstyle \mathcal{I}_f=\{A\subseteq \mathbf{N}: \lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{a \in A\setminus \{1,\ldots,n\}}f(a)=0\}
$$
and as
$$
\textstyle \mathcal{I}_f=\{A\subseteq \mathbf{N}: \sum_{n \in A}\min(1,f(n))<\infty\}.
$$

Comment: Maybe I am missing something trivial, but I think we can simply take $\mu_1=\mu_f$, $I_1=\mathbb N$ and $\mu_k=0$ for $k\ne1$. (Here $\mu_f(A)=\sum_{k\in A} f(k)$.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak I was meaning "nondegerate" partition, otherwise I'd agree it is trivial